# Find a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n$, so that $p(x)\ne 0$ if we plug in $x$ from $\{0,1,2,..,p-1\}$, using addition and multiplication $\mod p$.

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic

> Find a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n$, so that $p(x)$ is never equal to $0$ if we plug in $x$ from $\{0,1,2,..,p-1\}$, using addition and multiplication $\mod p$.

**My answer :**
If make $p(x) = x(x-1)(x-2)...(x-(p-1)+1$ doesn't it satisfy the condition in the question?

Comment: Looks good to me.  Another (very similar!) approach might be to remark that $n^p\equiv n\pmod p$ for $n\in \{0, \cdots, p-1\}$ so take $x^p-x+1$.

Comment: The idea works, but you need to tweak it a bit for $n \ne p$.

Comment: your polynomial does not meet the conditions because it has degree p but not n.

Comment: @dxiv are you referring to my polynomial or lulu's polynomial?

Comment: @miracle that's right. I completely missed it. How can I correct it then?

Comment: @dxiv can you help me for the case $n\ne p$?

Comment: @Itachi It is not clear whether the question asks for *one* polynomial of degree $n$ where you get to choose the degree (in which case both your polynomial and lulu's work, with $n=p$), or asks for a polynomial of degree $n$ for a given but otherwise arbitrary $n$ (in which case such a polynomial does not necessarily exist e.g. the $n=1$ counterexample in the posted answer).

Comment: @dxiv yes there were no other information about $n$ and $p$. Let's assume that it's said to find for arbitrary $n$. So if I write that for $n=p$ it's always possible but for arbitrary $n$ it doesn't necessarily exist, giving the counter example, then do you think it's a good way to answer this question?

Comment: for n=1 such a polynomial does not exist, because $x+a\equiv0 \pmod p$ for an $x \in \{0,...,p-1\}$

Comment: @Itachi That's technically correct, but whether that's the expected answer depends on context where the question was asked. (Also, it is straightforward to modify the examples to cover the case $n \gt p$, but the case $n \lt p$ may indeed have no solutions.)

Answer (score 2):

If the coefficients of the polynomial can be arbitrary numbers then
$$px^n+1$$ is such a polynomial of degree $n$. If we allow only coefficients from $0,\ldots,p-1$ it is not so simple. For $n=1$ and $p$ is a prime such a polynomial does not exist, because $$kx+d\equiv0 \pmod p$$ can be multiplied by the modular inverse of $k$ to get  $$x+a\equiv0 \pmod p$$ for   $x\equiv -a\pmod p$ .

if $p$ is not a prime but $p=uv, u,v>1$ then

$$ux+d\not\equiv 0 \pmod p$$

if $\gcd(u,d)=1$.

For $n=2$ and $p>2$ at least half of the numbers $1,\ldots,p-1$ do not have a square root $\pmod p$. So if $a$ has no square root such a polynomial exists: $$x^2-a$$ will not become $0 \pmod p$. This idea can be applied to arbitrary $n>1$:

So assume $p>1$  and $n>1$. For the polynomial
$$f(x)=x^n-x$$
the values $$f(0),f(1),\ldots,f(p-1)$$ are all from $\{0,\ldots,p-1\}$ but they are not all pairwise different $\pmod p$, because $$f(0)\equiv f(1)\equiv0\pmod p$$
So there is a value $$a \in \{0,\ldots,p-1\}\setminus \{f(0),f(1),\ldots,f(p-1)\}$$

Then expression
$$x^n-x-a$$
is a polynomial for $n>1$ and cannot become $0\pmod p$ for an $x$, if $p>1$.

Comment: Just to nitpick, you could further shorten it by noting that the last case $\,p \gt 1, n \gt 1\,$ subsumes the cases $\,p=2, n \gt 1\,$ and $\,n = 2, p \gt 2\,$ so there is no need to handle those separately.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you, I was aware of that. But now I stated this explicitly in my post.

Comment: The "*if $p \gt 2$*" condition in the last paragraph is not necessary, and is in fact not used in the previous argument. It is enough that $p \gt 1, n \gt 1$ for $x^n-x-a$ to have no roots.

Comment: @dxiv I see now, there is no special case p=2 necessary. It is necessary only for the square-root example, because there all numbers have a square root. Thank's agaiin